# Rx.Net TestScheduler How to replay events?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm trying to understand how to achieve the following in c#

I have a List of this class

```
public class StockTickerChangeHistory
{
    public DateTime Time;
    public string Stock;
}
```

I'd like to create an Observable that fires OnNext at the time specified by the Time member variable. I understand that Rx.Net ships with TestScheduler but I'm at a loss as to how to use it with the structure I have.

I've read this article but not sure how to convert it to c# as it appears to do exactly what I need.

https://blog.niallconnaughton.com/2015/05/09/time-travel-with-reactive-extensions/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ron.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `stocks` is an `IEnumerable<StockTickerChangeHistory>` ordered by `Time`

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

//Convert to array of OnNext notifications and create an Observable
var history = stocks.Select(i => OnNext(i.Time.Ticks, i)).ToArray();
var stockHistoryObservable = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(history);

//Create an observer and subscribe
var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<StockTickerChangeHistory>();
stockHistoryObservable.Subscribe(observer);

scheduler.AdvanceTo(dateWhenNoHistoryYet); //no history
observer.Messages.AssertEqual(); 
scheduler.AdvanceTo(dateWhenHistoryIsCompleted); //all history arrived
observer.Messages.AssertEqual(history);
```

Comment: @ronMilne did this answer your question?